# Como se chama aquele que responde perguntas?

Tags: vocabulário, palavra-para-ideia

Hoje no chat do [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com), estávamos falando sobre autores de perguntas e respostas, então surgiu a seguinte dúvida:

- Aquele que responde perguntas é um *respondente* ou um *respondedor*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Para se referir a quem responde uma pergunta eu sempre ouvi o termo [*respondente*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/respondente), em especial quando se fala de uma pesquisa. *Respondentes* é usado em alguns livros ([como este, na pág 308](https://books.google.com.br/books?isbn=854070062X) ou [este](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAFahUKEwiuzfna4ufHAhWGFpAKHeTwCZQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fdc.org.br%2Fprofessoresepesquisa%2Fnucleos%2FDocuments%2Fpesquisa_inovacao_nas_medias_empresas.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGNuCL0kGWjCkfg-o1vfRxBjDiJOw&sig2=UMjLadB1qMlA7s5oOUKjFQ&bvm=bv.102022582,d.Y2I)) para se referir àqueles que responderam as questões da pesquisa.

[*Respondedor*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/respondedor) parece um termo mais usado como uma crítica, como alguém que responde quando não deveria, um *respondão*.

Comment: Geralmente quem está respondendo perguntas é um entrevistado, inquerido, interrogado...

Comment: @AndréLyra os termos que citaste parece ser sinônimos mesmo. Podes criar uma resposta citando referências a elas?

Answer (score 3):

Quem responde perguntas:

- Em uma entrevista é o *entrevistado*, ou candidato à vaga.

  > O entrevistado respondeu à todas as questões do entrevistador.
- Em uma pesquisa pode ser *pessoa pesquisada*, *pessoa sondada*.

  > A amostra de pessoas pesquisadas a respeito do atual governo já é suficiente para nossa análise.
- Em um depoimento na delegacia ou em juízo é um *depoente* que foi inquirido (chamado a depor) para ser interrogado (ser questionado, responder perguntas sobre um fato).
- Em uma discussão, dilema é a *pessoa questionada*.

  > As pessoas envolvidas na desinteligência foram questionadas pelo policial.

  (Este exemplo é porque não se encaixa nos exemplos anteriores.)

Answer (score 0):

Acho que nisto o dicionário é deficitário.

A razão histórica pela escassez de termos, será decerto sociológica. Aquele que responde ver-lhe negado um termo que permitiría ao sujeito interrogado, objectivar a acção que o toma por objecto, e denominar a posição na qual é colocado por acção alheia.

Vê-se que as palavras para aquele que responde, são indissociáveis à posição social em que é posto ao responder.

> O interpelado.